# Jenkins: Deleted old builds are always rebuilt

Tags: git, github, jenkins

Setup:

1. Jenkins Freestyle job for Github (Enterprise)
2. Set Git refspec to: `+refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*`
3. Set Git Branch specifier to: `:.*\/pr\/\d+`
4. Set Poll SCM to Schedule `H/5 * * * *`
5. Make sure the build breaks fast (prebuild script that says `exit 1`)
6. Issue a few PRs and have them built

Test:

1. Delete some builds with the Jenkins console and this script:

```groovy
def jobName = 'myproject-pullrequests'
def from = 2;
def to = 5;
def reallyDelete = true;

// Range of builds to delete
def rs = Fingerprint.RangeSet.fromString(from+"-"+to, true);
// Set to true to actually delete. Use false to test the script.

// ----------------------------------
def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobName);
println("Job: ${job.fullName}");

def builds = job.getBuilds(rs);
println("Found ${builds.size()} builds");
builds.each{ b-> 
  if (reallyDelete) {
    println("Deleting ${b}");
    b.delete();
  } else {
    println("Found match ${b}");
  }
}
if (reallyDelete) {
    println("Setting next build number to ${from}");
    job.updateNextBuildNumber(from);
}
```

2. In your build job press "Build Now"

Expected:

- Next Build will continue with the next PR, if any.
  Result:
- Previously deleted builds are built again.

This is annoying if there are old builds that should just be discarded.

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

ps: Same result if builds are deleted manually.

Comment: I don't think this is related to git.

Comment: Jenkins has a config to ignore branches that are older than a certain age and that makes a lot of sense to set up for PR builds like that. If you simply delete the jobs Jenkins doesn't "know" that those builds already existed and have been deleted. It just sees branches without builds and fixes that.

Comment: @eftshift0: because it is related to the Jenkins git plugin and it might just not be happening with another scm, tagging it with git is a valid thing to do.

Comment: @JoachimSauer "Jenkins has a config to ignore branches that are older than a certain age" 
can you be a little more specific? I don't see any setting like this. There is a max days to keep option and max #builds option, but branch age is not mentioned and I don't see it mentioned here either: https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/

Comment: @Brixomatic: I find it incredibly hard/frustrating to find and/or link Jenkins documentation outside of that provided by specific instances. So I can at most tell you that I was thinking of "Multibranch Pipelines" which allow you to configure that as part of configuring a branch source. I don't know if you can do the same in a simple freestyle project, sorry.

Comment: ..also I'm deleting builds, not jobs, huge difference. Ya, so maybe it's specific to multibranch pipelines, thanks anyway.